# Improvment of Performance from VBA Program

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote my first VBA program to help me identify hardware with specific configuration. (With a lot of help from other Posts on StackOverflow :)

After some trying and error I wrote this short code, which works nicely but takes a Long time to run.

I wonder if you can help me improve the performance of this Code, as it is my first one, I guess I didn't use all the Tools I could.

Throughout the development process, before reaching this final code, I experimented with other functions to find the strings I needed in the cells, such as "Find". Using this function resulted in a faster processing, but the information was copied to the new sheet in a messy way. I could not figure why, so I changed tactics.

Although, this Version I am posting here works, it takes a Long time to execute.

```
'Code Title: Search Hardware with required DuagonFW and IBC Platform Softwares

'#########'
'Objective'
'#########'

'This Macro provides a list of hardwares with the configuration, input by the user

Option Explicit

Sub SearchConfiguration()


'###############'
'User input part'
'###############'

'Variable declaration for the input from user

Dim Hardware As Workbook
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim InfoSheet As Worksheet

'Set of Workbook and Sheets

Set Hardware = ThisWorkbook
Set DSheet = Hardware.Worksheets("Data")
Set InfoSheet = Hardware.Worksheets("Info")

'Variable declaration for the DuagonFW and IBC Platform

Dim DuagonFW As Variant
Dim ibc_platform As Variant

'Setting Information Table Head

InfoSheet.Activate
InfoSheet.Cells.Clear
InfoSheet.Range("A1").Value = "S/N"
InfoSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Duagon FW"
InfoSheet.Range("C1").Value = "IBC PLatform"
InfoSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Searched Duagon FW"
InfoSheet.Range("E1").Value = "Searched IBC PLatform"


'Getting configuration from user

GettingConfig:

    Dim ANS As Integer

    DuagonFW = InputBox("Insert the Duagon Firmware Number in the format d-xxxxxx-xxxxxx", vbDefaultButton1)

        If DuagonFW = vbNullString Then
            ANS = MsgBox("User canceled!", vbCritical)
            Exit Sub
        End If

    ibc_platform = InputBox("Insert the Duagon Firmware Number in the format Vxx.xx.xxxx", vbDefaultButton1)

        If ibc_platform = vbNullString Then
            ANS = MsgBox("User canceled!", vbCritical)
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Dim ConfigSpecifications As Variant

    ConfigSpecifications = MsgBox("The required configuration entered was: " & vbNewLine & "Duagon Firmware: " & DuagonFW _
    & vbNewLine & "IBC PLatform: " & ibc_platform & vbNewLine & "*Press No to retry", vbYesNoCancel, "CID06A Configuration")

    'Select Case ConfigSpecifications
        If ConfigSpecifications = vbNullString Or ConfigSpecifications = 2 Then
            ANS = MsgBox("User canceled!", vbCritical)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ConfigSpecifications = 1 Then
            InfoSheet.Range("D2").Value = DuagonFW
            InfoSheet.Range("E2").Value = ibc_platform
        End If
        If ConfigSpecifications = 7 Then
            GoTo GettingConfig
        End If

'##############################################################'
'Searching on the data the Hardwares with the required configuration'
'##############################################################'

'Activating Data Worksheet
DSheet.Activate

'Declaration of counters for the loop
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

'Setting counter
y = 1

'Loop through cells to compare strings with the input string and copy to the Information Table
    For x = 1 To 235
        If InStr(1, Cells(x, 7).Value, DuagonFW) > 0 And InStr(1, Cells(x, 8).Value, ibc_platform) > 0 Then
            y = y + 1
            Cells(x, 2).Copy InfoSheet.Range("A" & y)
            Cells(x, 7).Copy InfoSheet.Range("B" & y)
            Cells(x, 8).Copy InfoSheet.Range("C" & y)
        End If
    Next x

'Activation from information table
InfoSheet.Activate

'################'
'Formatting table'
'################'


Dim LstObj As ListObject
Dim rngDB As Range, n As Integer

        With InfoSheet
            Set rngDB = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion
            For Each LstObj In InfoSheet.ListObjects
                LstObj.Unlist
            Next
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngDB) > 0 Then
                n = n + 1
                Set LstObj = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngDB, , xlYes)
                With LstObj

                    .Name = "Table" & n
                    .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
                End With
            End If
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using `Cells(x, 2).Copy InfoSheet.Range("A" & y)` try `Cells(x, 2) = InfoSheet.Range("A" & y)`.  Also since this code is working, I would post it on Code Review instead.

Comment: I believe this is better suited for our siter site [codereview.se].

Comment: One way would be to filter your sheet with your requirements. Capture displayed range in an array and then paste it

Comment: I agree with the recommendation for [codereview.se]. Tangential: you don't need to capitalize all those nouns. For example, the sentence ending with "this Code" looks awkward. Just use "this code".

Comment: Sorry, my computer does that capitalization automatically... Germans, hehe!
It is my first post too.
Will put on Code Review

Thanks

Comment: I didn't think about using the filter. I will try. Thanks Zac.
Good Point Zack E, will try it also.
Thanks peeps

Comment: Zack E Suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Turning off screen updating with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of the code and turning it on again at the end is always a good tip for performance. Otherwise you could add lines `debug.print timer` in to the code to see which part takes the longest to process

Comment: You are right Joost, thank you for the comment, it got even faster!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Value to value2 is a good practice. 
Changing a lot of names objects for WITH is a good practice too. 
Stop using Activate , use Values , u dont need to activate anithing on excel just use the properties. 
A did a little upgraded , hope u can uderstand.

```
 Sub SearchConfiguration()


    '###############'
    'User input part'
    '###############'

    'Variable declaration for the input from user

    Dim Hardware As Workbook
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim InfoSheet As Worksheet

    'Set of Workbook and Sheets

    Set Hardware = ThisWorkbook
    Set DSheet = Hardware.Worksheets("Data")
    Set InfoSheet = Hardware.Worksheets("Info")

    'Variable declaration for the DuagonFW and IBC Platform

    Dim DuagonFW As Variant
    Dim ibc_platform As Variant

    'Setting Information Table Head
    With InfoSheet
        .Activate
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1").Value2 = "S/N"
        .Range("B1").Value2 = "Duagon FW"
        .Range("C1").Value2 = "IBC PLatform"
        .Range("D1").Value2 = "Searched Duagon FW"
        .Range("E1").Value2 = "Searched IBC PLatform"
    End With


    'Getting configuration from user

GettingConfig:

        Dim ANS As Integer

        DuagonFW = InputBox("Insert the Duagon Firmware Number in the format d-xxxxxx-xxxxxx", vbDefaultButton1)

            If DuagonFW = vbNullString Then
                ANS = MsgBox("User canceled!", vbCritical)
                Exit Sub
            End If

        ibc_platform = InputBox("Insert the Duagon Firmware Number in the format Vxx.xx.xxxx", vbDefaultButton1)

            If ibc_platform = vbNullString Then
                ANS = MsgBox("User canceled!", vbCritical)
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Dim ConfigSpecifications As Variant

        ConfigSpecifications = MsgBox("The required configuration entered was: " & vbNewLine & "Duagon Firmware: " & DuagonFW _
        & vbNewLine & "IBC PLatform: " & ibc_platform & vbNewLine & "*Press No to retry", vbYesNoCancel, "CID06A Configuration")

        'Select Case ConfigSpecifications
            If ConfigSpecifications = vbNullString Or ConfigSpecifications = 2 Then
                ANS = MsgBox("User canceled!", vbCritical)
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf ConfigSpecifications = 1 Then
                InfoSheet.Range("D2").Value2 = DuagonFW
                InfoSheet.Range("E2").Value2 = ibc_platform
            ElseIf ConfigSpecifications = 7 Then
                GoTo GettingConfig
            End If

    '##############################################################'
    'Searching on the data the Hardwares with the required configuration'
    '##############################################################'

    'Activating Data Worksheet
    DSheet.Activate

    'Declaration of counters for the loop
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    'Setting counter
    y = 1

    'Loop through cells to compare strings with the input string and copy to the Information Table
        For x = 1 To 235
            If InStr(1, Cells(x, 7).Value, DuagonFW) > 0 And InStr(1, Cells(x, 8).Value, ibc_platform) > 0 Then
                y = y + 1
                Cells(x, 2).Value2 = InfoSheet.Range("A" & y)
                Cells(x, 7).Value2 InfoSheet.Range("B" & y)
                Cells(x, 8).Value2 InfoSheet.Range("C" & y)
            End If
        Next x

    'Activation from information table
    InfoSheet.Activate

    '################'
    'Formatting table'
    '################'


    Dim LstObj As ListObject
    Dim rngDB As Range, n As Integer

            With InfoSheet
                Set rngDB = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion
                For Each LstObj In InfoSheet.ListObjects
                    LstObj.Unlist
                Next
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngDB) > 0 Then
                    n = n + 1
                    Set LstObj = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngDB, , xlYes)
                    With LstObj

                        .Name = "Table" & n
                        .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
                    End With
                End If
            End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Ronan. I understood, and will apply your suggestions from now on. :)